# Apache RewriteRule pass entire URL as a parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently my Apache `RewriteRule` only passes the path of the original URL as a query parameter to the rewritten URL.

How do I send the entire URL (including scheme and authority etc) as a parameter to the rewritten URL?

I know `%{REQUEST_URI}` only passes the path, and I can’t see any Apache environment variables that do pass the entire URL.

I’m something of a beginner to Apache configuration so excuse any ignorance on my part,

thanks!

Here’s my current config:

```
#
# Enable Rewrite
#

RewriteEngine On

#
# Condition for rewriting the URL. Check the URL's path is a valid REST URI path
#

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?:[^?#]*)(?:/v[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)*)(?:/[a-z]+)(?:/[a-z]+)(?:/?[^/?#]*)(?:[^?#]*)$

#
# Rewrite the URL, sending the REST path as a parameter to the specified version.
#

RewriteRule ^(?:[^?#]*)(?:/(v[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)*))((?:/[a-z]+)(?:/[a-z]+)(?:/?[^/?#]*)(?:[^?#]*))$ https://localhost/rest/$1/index.php?request_uri_path=https://localhost/rest/$1/$2 [QSA,NC,L,R=307]
```

Currently I’ve hardcoded the url into the query parameters so the URL

```
https://localhost/rest/v1/users/show/12345
```

becomes:

```
https://localhost/rest/v1/index.php?request_uri_path=https://localhost/rest/v1/users/show/12345
```

Comment: Which version of apache is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this rule to get full URL as query parameter:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ index.php?request_uri_path=http%1://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```

If you're on Apache 2.4 then you can make use of `%{REQUEST_SCHEME}` variable:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php?request_uri_path=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks, where exactly is `%1` defined? does each rule return a corresponding index-value? E.g `%0`, `%1` and so on?

Comment: `%1` is what we're getting from 2nd `RewriteCond` here. It can be `s` for `https` OR an empty string for `http`.

Comment: If it were Apache 2.4, using "%{REQUEST_SCHEME}://...` would also work =)

Comment: Thanks, Yes that's right, I will update the answer for Apache 2.4 as well.