# pass all segments of url( along with query string params) in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I would like to pass a query string with the full url. I would like to rewrite a url like:

```
host/admin?lang=en
```

to

```
host/index.php?url=admin?lang=en
```

I use the following instructions in htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$   ./index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But this pass only before the '?' sign in the url . and doesn't pass the query string

How can I solve this? thanks...

Comment: what do you get when you print `print_r($_GET)` from `index.php`?

Comment: @anubhava for example when the requested url is : localhost/posts?lang=fa and i print the $_GET['url']. only 'posts' string was printed

Comment: Comment out first rule completely and test with this only this rule in place

Comment: @anubhava the first rule is for removing trailing slashes. so i commented that but the problem not resolved

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33506089/apache-rewriterule-pass-entire-url-as-a-parameter

Comment: @JoniJnm I tested it. but doesn't work too. it doesn't pass the query string parameters

Comment: @SirwanRauofi Did you add %{QUERY_STRING} ?